# Swift: Remove from array of strings any element that contains a string from another array

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

I have array1 and filter it so that any of its elements that contain any of the strings in array2 are removed:

```
var array1 = ["first.food", "second.easy.good", "third.long.bad", "4.bad.apple", "cinco.Thank You!"]

let array2 = ["food", "bad"]
```

Desired result: array1 = ["second.easy.good", "cinco.Thank You!"]

I achieve this by looping over array2 and filtering array1,

```
    for string in array2 {
        array1 = array1.filter { !$0.contains(string) }
    }
```

result: array1 = ["second.easy.good", "cinco.Thank You!"]

But can it be done in one line? And if so would it be more or less efficient?

edit: removing the word "functionally" from the question based on accepted reply by @matt.

(Previous question: But can it be done functionally in one line? And if so would it be more or less efficient?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> functionally in one line ... efficient?

Efficiency might come from parsing the dot-strings into a Set, and especially from turning the second array into a Set, so that `contains` is faster; in fact, if they are both sets, you can use `intersection`, which is insanely efficient.

This would be worth while particularly if the quantities are large, as the preparation does take a little time.

```
// your premise
let array1 = ["first.food", "second.easy.good", "third.long.bad", "4.bad.apple", "cinco.Thank You!"]
let array2 = ["food", "bad"]

// preparation
let parsedArray1 = array1.map {($0, Set($0.split(separator: ".").map(String.init)))}
let set2 = Set(array2)

// okay, _now_ we can be efficient!
let result = parsedArray1.filter { $0.1.intersection(set2).isEmpty }.map {$0.0}

// done! proof:
print(result) // ["second.easy.good", "cinco.Thank You!"]
```

But that has *nothing* to do with "functional programming", which is merely a way of talking, not a way of improving efficiency. Nor is the "number of lines" of the slightest relevance to efficiency; a one-liner (like my `let result` line) is fun to look at, but it has no effect whatever on what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: ok, that is useful info thanks. I used the word "functionally" solely in an attempt to clarify that I was looking to subsume the for next loop into the filter's closure which would remove 2 lines of code.

Comment: And that is what my answer shows you how to do. But be aware that a for loop expressed functionally is still a loop; it's just hidden, that's all.